# How to send a counter-offer when an AI civilization initiates a trade

Tags: civilization-beyond-earth

Samatar Jama Barre would really, really like to trade me for some Firaxite. So, he's sent a couple trade requests seeking 1 Firaxite for 90 turns in exchange for a favor. I'm not particularly enamored by this offer and would like to negotiate a counter offer.

It appears that my only two options are to accept or refuse. Refusing appears to end the trade negotiations with the only choice left to make is determining how insulting my parting words should be. How can I make a counter offer instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunally, this is not possible in Civilization: Beyond Earth, you can not counter-offer a trade to an AI civilization for whatever reason.

Comment: Disappointing....

Comment: @Ellesedil I'm sorry :( Go complain to the devs who created the game, they might fix it in a later patch.

Comment: On a side note I once played a facebook game called the pawn stars (never again) and they had a haggling feature to the game where I could counter-offer what the AI wanted, and it was really buggy. By that I mean he could offer to sell the item to me for $120, I offer $100, he counters $110 and then I offer $40 and he accepts. Maybe it was to hard to implement something like that?

Answer (score 1):

I have experienced two different situations when an AI initiates a trade:

1. The trade screen **does not** include any of the typical content (energy, science, resources, favors, etc) and the only options are accept and refuse. In this scenario, you have no opportunity to change the deal. This typically includes the AI proposing a favor in exchange for something, but not always. If you accept this type of deal, you will get a diplomatic boost with that AI. As far as I know, if you refuse, you do not receive a penalty. (Please correct me if that is wrong.)
2. The trade screen **does** include the typical content. In this case, you can tweak things to your liking and even change the offer entirely. In this case, the AI is simply offering you a trade. Just like with human opponents, you can modify the deal and send it back.

Comment: So in my case, the AI wanted a strategic resource (Firaxite) and was offering a favor in return. This resulted in the trade screen you refer to in scenario 1. Is this a slight deviation from Civ 5 (I haven't played it)?

Comment: Ah, I see. In the case that an AI says something along the lines of "I need your help" and offers a favor, that is a subset of scenario 1, and you cannot change it. Yes, that is slightly varied from Civ 5, because favors did not exist. In Civ 5, the AI would ask that you straight-up give them something, like a friendly demand.